# Change key by other in keypress event or keydown event

Tags: javascript, extjs

When my user press "." I need that browser show ",".

I intent use this Extjs code buy don't work :(

```
Ext.EventManager.on(document, 'keypress', function(evt, t, o) {
    if (evt.keyCode == 46) { // .
        evt.keyCode = 44; // ,
    }
});
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

You are changing the value of the event, and that's not going to change the value of the resultant string.

You should replace the `.` for the `,`on the string ater you catch the event:

```
Ext.EventManager.on(document, 'keypress', function(evt, t, o) {
    if (evt.keyCode == 46) { // .
        resultantString.replace('.', ',');
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok, I use `t.value = t.value.replace('.', ',');` but I haven't spected result.

Comment: I don't know who voted positive, but your code don't work. resultantString is undefined.

Comment: Of course it's undefined. That's a variable with a generic name, you should name it the way you need to in order for that code to work!

Comment: Thanks drgomesp but your conde don't work. Keypress event is before that "resultantstring" (in my case t.value) has value. Your code only work with setTimeout... but it is a little crappy.

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I tried to say. Even though, try studying javascript a little more. That's really basic stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, this won't work, because you are merely changing the keyCode. That won't somehow reflect on the screen. You will have to locate the element that caused the event and set its text to (whatever was before) + (remove the .) + (,)

Of course, this is the long way out. I hope someone has a shorter way.

Comment: Obsviosly, I know that not work. I can't implement your solution, In keypress event my control don't have any "." yet... and I can't change it.

Comment: -1 for "Obviously", but +1 for saying where to change the resultant string.